# Eratosthenes-like sieve - infinitely many left unstruck?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sieve-theory

Given any infinite sequence $c_1,c_2...$ of natural numbers, if all of the natural numbers $x$ such that there exists $n$ such that $x\equiv c_n (\mod p_n)$ and $x \geq 2p$, where $p_n$ is the nth prime, are deleted from a list, must there be infinitely many natural numbers left on the list afterwards?

e.g. $c_i=1 \ \forall i\\
1,2,3,4,\not5,6,\not7,8,\not9,\not10,\not11,12,\not13,14,\not15,\not16,\not17,18,\not19,20...$

So far I only know about the trivial case where $c_i=0$, and I may have missed obvious counterexamples.

Comment: If you allow two c_i per p_i (e.g. c_i +/- 1) this is equivalent to the twin prime conjecture. Not sure about only a single c_i per p_i. If you have only a single unstruck number what you're actually generating are all the numbers that are p + 1 for some p. (you have a small error in that 14 is struck in your sequence, it should not be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are infinitely many natural numbers left afterwards.

When performing Eratosthenes' unmodified sieving operation, the striking out of multiples of $2$ eliminates $\frac12$ of the values greater than $2$; the striking out of multiples of $3$ eliminates $\frac13 (1 - \frac12) = \frac16$ of the values greater than $3$; the striking out of multiples of $5$ eliminates $\frac15 (1 - \frac12 - \frac16) = \frac1{15}$ of the values greater than $5$; etc.

With your offset sieve, the numbers struck out are different, but the proportions are exactly the same. The reason is simple: each prime number is (by definition) coprime with all smaller prime numbers. Therefore there is no correlation between the numbers which are struck out before reaching that prime and the numbers which are struck out by that prime, and regardless of the value of $c_i$ we strike out $\frac1{p_i}$ of the unstruck numbers $\ge 2p_i$.

Slightly more rigorously: since the $p_i$ are distinct primes, the LCM of a set of them is simply their product, and in particular $p_i$ is coprime with $\prod_{j<i} p_j$. Then consider the equivalent classes of $\mathbb{Z} / \prod_{j\le i} p_j \mathbb{Z}$: the Chinese remainder theorem gives us a natural bijection with the Cartesian product $(\mathbb{Z} / \prod_{j\lt i} p_j \mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z} / p_i \mathbb{Z})$. Then all elements who share a projection onto $\mathbb{Z} / \prod_{j\lt i} p_j \mathbb{Z}$ share a current status (struck out or not); and when we strike out the elements in which the projection onto $\mathbb{Z} / p_i \mathbb{Z}$ is $c_i$ we will strike out precisely $\frac1{p_i}$ of those which were not struck out (and re-strike the same proportion of those which were already struck out).

Therefore for any sequence $c_i$, and for any positive integer $C$, after striking out the values corresponding to the $j$th prime the number of unstruck numbers smaller than $C \prod_{k\le j}p_k$ will be at least as many as for the sequence $c_i = 0$ (and will not exceed that number by more than $j$, where the excess is due to numbers in $(p, 2p]$ not being struck out).

Comment: I think this is essentially right, but requires a lot more work to be made rigorous... the "proportion" needs to be well-defined. (You can't say, for instance, that it's the number of multiples struck out, divided by the total number of numbers: that's of the form $\infty/\infty$, and not very meaningful. Probably you need to look at numbers $\le N$ and let $N \to \infty$, but then the fractions are not exact, and you need to bound the error terms, etc.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, indeed. I was originally planning to talk in terms of equivalence classes modulo $\textrm{lcm}_{j \le i}(p_j)$, but I thought that would detract from the core intuition.

Comment: The no-correlation thing would make the probability of finitely many numbers being left 0 if the process were completely random, but is there any proof that the seive is "random" enough for such heuristics to apply?

Comment: @AngelaRichardson, CRT. I've expanded the answer to spell it out in more detail.

Comment: Just one thing I'm confused about. Does the proportion struck out mean the asymptotic density- the limit as $n \to \infty$ of how many $<n$ are struck out / $ n$? Although then the total proportion struck out would be $100\%$ for $c=0$ by the prime number theorem.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson, yes.

Comment: Something is funny / not right: I think the sum of the series $\frac12 + \frac16 + \frac1{15} + \dots$ is actually $1$ (related to what @AngelaRichardson observed about the prime number theorem: that for the sequence $c_i = 0$, the proportion of struck numbers less than $n$ is roughly $(n - \frac{n}{\ln n}) / n = 1 - \frac{1}{\ln n} \to 1$).

Comment: @AngelaRichardson, Shreevatsa's comment isn't a problem, but I think there might be a real one. Eratosthenes strikes all but one element of the equivalence class $0\pmod p_i$, but he guarantees that the unstruck one is not struck by any other prime. Your sieve strikes all but two elements of the equivalence class $c_i \pmod p_i$, but those elements may be struck by another prime. I'm not sure how to recover a guarantee of sufficient elements surviving.